# CasperJS/PhantomJS - Failed to save screenshot to <path>; please check permissions

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have a following piece of code:

```
casper.start('http://some-page.local');

casper.then(function () {
    this.capture(ss())
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    document.querySelector("input[name='x']").value = 'x'
    document.querySelector("input[name='y']").value = 'y'
    // document.querySelectorAll("form")[2].submit()
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.capture(ss())
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.capture(ss())
});

casper.run();
```

If I execute this piece of code, it works fine, all 3 screenshots are created.

If I decide to submit the form (uncomment `document.querySelectorAll("form")[2].submit()` line), an error is produced after first screenshot:

> [error] [phantom] Failed to save screenshot to C:/screenshots/0002.png;
>   please check permissions
>
> [error] [phantom] Failed to save screenshot to C:/screenshots/0002.png;
>   please check permissions

If `this.capture(ss())` in second `casper.then` call will be replaced to `this.captureSelector(ss(), 'html')`, error is gone.

Can anyone explain why is this happening? Is there a universal way to capture screenshots using Casper/Phantom that would not print such error?

Comment: First time I've seen this. Can you give the versions you're using (CasperJS/PhantomJS)?

Comment: Hey, sorry for late response. PhantomJS - v2.1.1, CasperJS - v.1.1.1